# django+nginx docker seems did not load static files

Tags: django, nginx, docker

I practice use docker deploy the django project
I modify the dockerfile in this project `https://github.com/andrecp/django-tutorial-docker-nginx-postgres`

And when I visit /docs/  (swagger), it seems it did not load the static files
But I didn't see the status which is not 200

[image]

And I try a url of my project got 500 error

nginx.conf

```
worker_processes 1;

events {

    worker_connections 1024;

}

http {

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.org;

        access_log /dev/stdout;
        error_log /dev/stdout info;

        location /static {
            alias /usr/src/app/static/static-only;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://django:8000;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
    }
}
```

How could the problem be??

And I don't know how to check the log

```
        access_log /dev/stdout;
        error_log /dev/stdout info;
```

I try `/dev/stdout info`
But got permission denied

nginx dockerfile:

```
# Set nginx base image
FROM nginx

# File Author / Maintainer
MAINTAINER Andre Prado

# Copy custom configuration file from the current directory
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

django dockerfile:

```
# Dockerfile for sample Django application

FROM python:2.7-onbuild

ENV DJANGO_CONFIGURATION Docker

RUN pip install -r /usr/src/app/requirements-test.txt

CMD ["gunicorn", "-c", "gunicorn_conf.py", "--chdir", "mysite", "mysite.wsgi:application", "--reload"]
```